# How to show error when action= not found php

Tags: php, action

Hii everyone i am new here, and i am also new in coding world too 
But i what i have learned so far from php by myself it feels nice using php.
But i have a queation
I have a file name (home.php)
I used

```
$action = $_GET("action")
```

In this page and i have multiple actions available fr the page it goes like

```
home.php?action=main

home.php?action=new
```

But when someone tries puting new action there that i dont have in the  file 
Like

```
home.php?action=boom
```

Page comes blank

Any one give me any idea to set a action that will come when an actio  not found in the file

Thank you very much

I know ifs a lot to ask
But its stack overflow

Comment: Hey, please add this at the top of your php file `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and tell me what is the error

Comment: Morover, `home.php?action=main home.php?action=new` should be `home.php?action=main home.php&action=new`, if you want several query in your url, you have to use & instead of ? to add them.

Comment: Can you post your code so we can help workout what is going wrong.

Comment: @Lucas good point, but I think he is saying they are two separate links not one long link

Comment: @Lucas: those are two different urls.

Comment: Make an array of allowed actions and use [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if the actual action is allowed (in the array of allowed actions)

Comment: https://afridi.pw/code.txt my code is this :)

Comment: @Mr.Afridi your page is blank because you don't have any action with the good name, use Will's answer, else add `else{}` conditon which could output something if the action doesn't exist

Comment: Okay ..! But any way of redirecting blank page to error page? error.php?

Comment: @Mr.Afridi you can use `die("Error : the action doesn't exist");` which would stop the execution of your file

Comment: @Mr.Afridi You can also use redirection, I use myself javascript redirection `<script> document.location.href="error.php"; </script>`

Comment: great,, Thank you very very much, that worked :)

Comment: @Mr.Afridi Which one did you use ?

Comment: No need for javascript, if php still haven't echoed anything you can use 
`header('Location: yourOtherPage.php'); `

Comment: i used the die tag, header tag isn't working its bring backs the blank page,

Comment: @Will I guess that header won't work because there is html before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple solution can be :

```
$action = $_GET["action"];

switch ($action) {
    case "main":
        // do your main stuff here
        break;
    case "new":
        // do your new stuff here
        break;
    default:
       // the action is unknown, do what you have to do in that case here
}
```

But that makes you add each new action manually, probably not the best way to do it.
Still, it is a simple way to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can  also try this :

```
$action = $_GET("action");
if($action=='main'){
    // do your main stuff here
}else if($action=='new'){
    // do your main stuff here
}else{
    // do your main stuff here
}
```

if action does not match in any condition then by default it will go on else case.